# How to inject sporran wallet in react js application?

Tags: did, kilt

I wan't to integrate sporran wallet in my reactjs application. Could someone point me some resources. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to use the [Sporran Wallet](https://www.sporran.org/) to do some kind of authentication using DIDs or Verifiable Credentials that the users hold in their wallets.

You have to implement first your logic using the [KILT SDK](https://github.com/KILTprotocol/sdk-js) (see the documentation [here](https://docs.kilt.io/docs/develop/sdk/quickstart/)). Can take a look into [DIDsign](https://github.com/BTE-Trusted-Entity/didsign).